# MySQL Average score by category

Tags: php, mysql

Im stuck once again with a mysql query that I can not figure out unless I write many queries inside other queries.

I have 10 columns. 5 survey answer columns, 5 answer category columns.

```
qone_answer, qone_answer_cat
qtwo_answer, qtwo_answer_cat
qthree_answer, qthree_answer_cat
qfour_answer, qfour_answer_cat
qfive_answer, qfive_answer_cat
```

There are a total of 5 categories. When a survey is created, a category is chosen for each of the 5 questions.

I.E. Question 1 might be category 4 - Question 2 might be category 2. Etc, etc.

My task is to query the table and get the average rating for each of the 5 categories.

The only way I can accomplish this is to perform a query for each answer and each answer_category, but this will be 25 queries, and it cant be the most efficient way of doing this.

Way I came up with:

```
  $slot_one_category_one = "SELECT AVG(answer_one) as slot_one_answer_one_avg FROM response_storage WHERE answer_one_category='1'";
  $slot_two_category_one = "SELECT AVG(answer_one) as slot_two_answer_one_avg FROM response_storage WHERE answer_two_category='1'";
  $slot_three_category_one = "SELECT AVG(answer_one) as slot_two_answer_one_avg FROM response_storage WHERE answer_three_category='1'";
```

etc. etc. etc for each slot and each cat.

In the end, I need to find every answer_category equal to 1, and get the answer, store that, and continue with the loop.. Then do this for every answer_category equal to 2, then 3, then 4, then 5 - Totaling 25 queries.

Can anyone help me with a better method to do this?

Here is an early attempt done another way, but it does get the point across of what Im trying to do. The column names are a little different in this example, but its the same idea.. Question & Question category:

```
$survey_category_totals = mysql_query("SELECT question_one,qone_cat FROM survey WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($survey_category_totals))
{
$cat_question_one = $row['question_one'];
$cat_cat_one = $row['qone_cat'];
    if ($cat_cat_one==1){
        $category_one_total=$category_one_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_one_count=$category_one_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==2){
        $category_two_total=$category_two_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_two_count=$category_two_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==3){
        $category_three_total=$category_three_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_three_count=$category_three_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==4){
        $category_four_total=$category_four_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_four_count=$category_four_count+1;            
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==5){
        $category_five_total=$category_five_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_five_count=$category_five_count+1;            
    }                               
}
$survey_category_totals = mysql_query("SELECT question_two,qtwo_cat FROM survey WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($survey_category_totals))
{
$cat_question_one = $row['question_two'];
$cat_cat_one = $row['qtwo_cat'];
    if ($cat_cat_one==1){
        $category_one_total=$category_one_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_one_count=$category_one_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==2){
        $category_two_total=$category_two_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_two_count=$category_two_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==3){
        $category_three_total=$category_three_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_three_count=$category_three_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==4){
        $category_four_total=$category_four_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_four_count=$category_four_count+1;            
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==5){
        $category_five_total=$category_five_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_five_count=$category_five_count+1;            
    }                               
}   
$survey_category_totals = mysql_query("SELECT question_three,qthree_cat FROM survey WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($survey_category_totals))
{
$cat_question_one = $row['question_three'];
$cat_cat_one = $row['qthree_cat'];
    if ($cat_cat_one==1){
        $category_one_total=$category_one_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_one_count=$category_one_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==2){
        $category_two_total=$category_two_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_two_count=$category_two_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==3){
        $category_three_total=$category_three_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_three_count=$category_three_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==4){
        $category_four_total=$category_four_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_four_count=$category_four_count+1;            
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==5){
        $category_five_total=$category_five_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_five_count=$category_five_count+1;            
    }                               
}   
$survey_category_totals = mysql_query("SELECT question_four,qfour_cat FROM survey WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($survey_category_totals))
{
$cat_question_one = $row['question_four'];
$cat_cat_one = $row['qfour_cat'];
    if ($cat_cat_one==1){
        $category_one_total=$category_one_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_one_count=$category_one_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==2){
        $category_two_total=$category_two_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_two_count=$category_two_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==3){
        $category_three_total=$category_three_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_three_count=$category_three_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==4){
        $category_four_total=$category_four_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_four_count=$category_four_count+1;            
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==5){
        $category_five_total=$category_five_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_five_count=$category_five_count+1;            
    }                               
}   
$survey_category_totals = mysql_query("SELECT question_five,qfive_cat FROM survey WHERE clinic_id='$clinic_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($survey_category_totals))
{
$cat_question_one = $row['question_five'];
$cat_cat_one = $row['qfive_cat'];
    if ($cat_cat_one==1){
        $category_one_total=$category_one_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_one_count=$category_one_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==2){
        $category_two_total=$category_two_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_two_count=$category_two_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==3){
        $category_three_total=$category_three_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_three_count=$category_three_count+1;          
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==4){
        $category_four_total=$category_four_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_four_count=$category_four_count+1;            
    }
    if ($cat_cat_one==5){
        $category_five_total=$category_five_total+$cat_question_one;
        $category_five_count=$category_five_count+1;            
    }                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll really just need 5 queries, unioned together to be one big query.

```
SELECT AVG(answer_one) AS slot_one, answer_one_category
FROM response_storage
GROUP BY answer_one_category
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(answer_two) AS slot_two, answer_two_category
FROM response_storage
GROUP BY answer_two_category
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(answer_three) AS slot_three, answer_three_category
FROM response_storage
GROUP BY answer_three_category
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(answer_four) AS slot_four, answer_four_category
FROM response_storage
GROUP BY answer_four_category
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(answer_five) AS slot_five, answer_five_category
FROM response_storage
GROUP BY answer_five_category
```

That will return two columns. The average answers for each slot/category combination, which should be 25 records.

If you just need the average answer by category then you can union each answer and category for each question, then take the average:

```
SELECT
    category,
    avg(answer) average_answer
FROM
    (
        SELECT answer_one as answer, answer_one_category as category FROM response_storage      
        UNION ALL
        SELECT answer_two as answer, answer_two_category as category FROM response_storage      
        UNION ALL
        SELECT answer_three as answer, answer_three_category as category FROM response_storage      
        UNION ALL
        SELECT answer_four as answer, answer_four_category as category FROM response_storage        
        UNION ALL
        SELECT answer_five as answer, answer_five_category as category FROM response_storage        
    )subtbl
GROUP BY 1
```

The funny thing is that the UNION here actually puts the results in a format that would have been more appropriate for the table schema in the beginning (which is why this feels so painful). A good schema would be  `QuestionNumber | Category | Answer` which would make your request simple with something like: `SELECT avg(answer), category FROM response_storage GROUP BY category`. This would also have the added benefit of allowing you to add questions in the future with out altering your table structure.

Comment: I need 5 numbers in the end. 1 for each category.

Comment: Added more to the answer to include that.